# CJSONDeserialize error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, touchjson

I am working on a JSON parsing application. I am using touchjson for parsing the json url which is --

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/746330/facts.json

```
{
"title":"About Canada",
"rows":[
    {
    "title":"Beavers",
    "description":"Beavers are second only to humans in their ability to manipulate and change their environment. They can measure up to 1.3 metres long. A group of beavers is called a colony",
    "imageHref":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/American_Beaver.jpg/220px-American_Beaver.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Flag",
    "description":null,
    "imageHref":"http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/662/world_flag/128/flag_of_canada.png"
    },
    {
    "title":"Transportation",
    "description":"It is a well known fact that polar bears are the main mode of transportation in Canada. They consume far less gas and have the added benefit of being difficult to steal.",
    "imageHref":"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_VZVOmYVm68Q/SMkzZzkGXKI/AAAAAAAAADQ/U89miaCkcyo/s400/the_golden_compass_still.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Hockey Night in Canada",
    "description":"These Saturday night CBC broadcasts originally aired on radio in 1931. In 1952 they debuted on television and continue to unite (and divide) the nation each week.",
    "imageHref":"http://fyimusic.ca/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/hockey-night-in-canada.thumbnail.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Eh",
    "description":"A chiefly Canadian interrogative utterance, usually expressing surprise or doubt or seeking confirmation.",
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Housing",
    "description":"Warmer than you might think.",
    "imageHref":"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/alaska/256/Igloo-icon.png"
    },
    {
    "title":"Public Shame",
    "description":" Sadly it's true.",
    "imageHref":"http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Music/Pix/site_furniture/2007/04/19/avril_lavigne.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":null,
    "description":null,
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Space Program",
    "description":"Canada hopes to soon launch a man to the moon.",
    "imageHref":"http://files.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_07_14__10_25_15/trebucheta.jpgdf3f3bf4-935d-40ff-84b2-6ce718a327a9Larger.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Meese",
    "description":"A moose is a common sight in Canada. Tall and majestic, they represent many of the values which Canadians imagine that they possess. They grow up to 2.7 metres long and can weigh over 700 kg. They swim at 10 km/h. Moose antlers weigh roughly 20 kg. The plural of moose is actually 'meese', despite what most dictionaries, encyclopedias, and experts will tell you.",
    "imageHref":"http://caroldeckerwildlifeartstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/IMG_2418%20majestic%20moose%201%20copy%20(Small)-96x96.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Geography",
    "description":"It's really big.",
    "imageHref":null
    },
    {
    "title":"Kittens...",
    "description":"Éare illegal. Cats are fine.",
    "imageHref":"http://www.donegalhimalayans.com/images/That%20fish%20was%20this%20big.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Mounties",
    "description":"They are the law. They are also Canada's foreign espionage service. Subtle.",
    "imageHref":"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/__mokxbTmuJM/RnWuJ6cE9cI/AAAAAAAAATw/6z3m3w9JDiU/s400/019843_31.jpg"
    },
    {
    "title":"Language",
    "description":"Nous parlons tous les langues importants.",
    "imageHref":null
    }
]
}
```

For some reason i am getting the error when i use CJONDeserializer ---

> Error Domain=CJSONDeserializerErrorDomain Code=-104 "Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a value." UserInfo=0x7feb38d99ed0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not scan dictionary. Failed to scan a value., line=0, character=0, location=0, snippet=!HERE>!{
>   "title":"About Can}

and if I use NSJSONSerializer it gives me the following error ---

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 2643.) UserInfo=0x7f8559c56700 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 2643.}”

For the code I am using, it doesn't give me any error if I use any other json url.

Here is the code that I am using --

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *receivedDataDictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:self.receivedData error:&error];

    NSArray *arrayFromJson = [receivedDataDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in arrayFromJson) {
        NSLog(@"blah %@", tempDict);
    }

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing from your JSON : "title" doesnt contain array, array is in key "rows".

Second : It looks like Problem is in your JSON. Your JSON contains "É" in third last object. `CJSONDeserializer` is not able to decode this kind of chars. Use `NSJSONSerialization`. Try following code.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error];

NSData *resData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error) {
    //Error handling
} else {
    //use your json object
     NSArray *arrayFromJson = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"rows"];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in arrayFromJson) {
         NSLog(@"blah %@", tempDict);
    }
}
```